# SQL query for a group based on last updated

Tags: mysql

i know there are lot of questions using max.But looks like i am not getting how to query

i would like to query a last completed record based on the hash group.

**table values:**

> **hash|method_name     |event_name|end_time**
>
> 123 |method1         | event1   | 2018-07-28 02:16:28
>
> 123 |method2         | event2   | 2018-07-28 02:17:28
>
> 123 |method3         | event3   | 2018-07-28 02:18:28
>
> 456 |method2         | event1   | 2018-07-28 02:18:00
>
> 678 |method2         | event1   | 2018-07-28 02:20:00
>
> 156 |method1         | event1   | 2018-07-28 02:10:28
>
> 156 |method2         | event2   | 2018-07-28 02:11:29
>
> 156 |method3         | event3   | 2018-07-28 02:12:30
>
> 963 |method3         | event3   | 2018-07-28 02:16:30
>
> 103 |method3         | event3   | 2018-07-28 02:15:30

**result:**

> **hash|method_name     |event_name|end_time**
>
> 123 |method1         | event1   | 2018-07-28 02:16:28
>
> 123 |method2         | event2   | 2018-07-28 02:17:28
>
> 123 |method3         | event3   | 2018-07-28 02:18:28
>
> 678 |method2         | event1   | 2018-07-28 02:20:00
>
> 963 |method3         | event3   | 2018-07-28 02:16:30

Query which solved my problem.

```
select * from table_name where hash in (select hash from table_name group by method_name having max(end_time));
```

Comment: based on the above table values.I would like to query the below mentioned result.Sorry i am new to mysql complex queries.

Comment: What does "completed record" mean?

Comment: add your current query and its result

Comment: wherever end_time is set , i assume that it is a completed event.If not sent its in execution.

Comment: Basically i want Last updated record for a particular method_name and event_name group.No duplicate values should come unless it comes in some other hash group with multiple events i am okay.

Comment: Could you explain why in your expected result there is row with hash = 963 and there is no row with hash = 456?

Comment: @NikitaU. 456 got rejected as 678 was the latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
select * from table_name where hash in 
(select hash from table_name group by method_name having max(end_time));
```

Comment: This helps.I queried hash with group by method_name having max(end_time)..Thanks

Comment: so the right query is SELECT *
FROM table
GROUP BY method_name having MAX(end_time); ?

Comment: select * from table_name where hash in (select hash from table_name group by method_name having max(end_time));
This one worked for me

Comment: select * will give a single record per group which has max end_time.But i need all the records which satisfies the condition.